# Как использовать StringBuilder для нескольких элементов? Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Есть код для парсинга и внесения некоторых изменений в выводимый текст:

```
Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(contentUrl).get();
                imagesRec = doc.select("div.post-featured-img amp-img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
                imgSrcUrl = imagesRec.attr("abs:src");


                contentPrepared = new StringBuilder();


                for (Element p : doc.select("div.amp-wp-article-content p, div.amp-wp-article-content h2, div.amp-wp-article-content h3, div.amp-wp-article-content cite")) {
                    contentPrepared.append(p.text());
                    contentPrepared.append("\n" + "\n");
                }

                for (Element p : doc.select("div.amp-wp-article-content li")) {
                    contentPrepared.append(p.text());
                    contentPrepared.append("-----");
                }


                contentFinal = contentPrepared.toString();
```

Как видно из кода, я хочу взять классы `div.amp-wp-article-content p`, `div.amp-wp-article-content h2`, `div.amp-wp-article-content h3` и `div.amp-wp-article-content cite` и вставить между ними новые строки, и это отлично работает.

Вся проблема во второй "вставке", точнее в конечном виде текста. Я хочу взять класс `div.amp-wp-article-content li` и вставить перед ним "-----". Все это работает, но при выводе на экран сначала выводится содержимое тегов с первого `StringBuilder`, а затем уже, в конце страницы, содержимое тега со второго `StringBuilder`.

Вопрос: **как вывести элементы в том порядке, в котором они должны быть на странице?** Т.е. текст внутри тега `div.amp-wp-article-content li` должен располагаться не в конце страницы, а между тегами с первого StrinBuilder'а.

Comment: Для этого, вам надо добавлять элементы в StringBuilder в том порядке, в коком вы хотите что б они были выведены на странице.

Comment: Так элементы со второго билдера располагаются между элементов первого билдера, в этом как бы и проблема.

Comment: Объединить поиск в один `select` и внутри цикла сделать проверку элемента: если это `li` - добавляем `"-----"`, если нет - `"\n\n"`

Comment: @woesss не могли бы вы привести пример данного условия, если не сложно?

Comment: for (Element p : doc.select("div.amp-wp-article-content li, div.amp-wp-article-content p, div.amp-wp-article-content h2, div.amp-wp-article-content h3, div.amp-wp-article-content cite")) {
                    contentPrepared.append(p.text());

                    if (p.text().contains("div.amp-wp-article-content li")) {
                        contentPrepared.append("-------");
                    } else{
                    contentPrepared.append("\n" + "\n");

                }}         естественно, не работает как нужно.